# Switching between skeletons using trackingIDs with Xbox Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to choose the skeleton that Kinect tracks using trackingID. When Kinect tracks a user everything is fine. However if a new user comes in the screen he takes control and I can't give control back to the first user, his trackingID is lost... Any idea?

Comment: Which version of Kinect are you using? The Xbox360 version (Kinect v1), or Kinect for Windows/Xbox One (Kinect v2)? And which porgramming language are you using? C# or C++?

Comment: I'm using Xbox360, In C#.